# Carácteres iguales en un arreglo de 2 dimensiones

Tags: java

Este es mi código:

```
public class Ejemplo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int cont1 = 0;

        char matriz[][] = 
        {   {'A','B','C','D','E','L'},
            {'A','B','C','D','E','1'},
            {'A','B','C','D','E','1'},
            {'A','B','C','D','E','1'},
            {'A','B','C','D','E','1'},
            {'A','B','D','D','D','D'}};


        for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("");
            for (int j=0; j<matriz[0].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(matriz[i][j] + " ");
            }
        }


        for (int i = 0; i<matriz.length; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<matriz[0].length; j++) {
                if ((matriz[i][j] == matriz[i][j + 1]) && (matriz[i][j + 1] == matriz[i][j + 2]) && (matriz[i][j + 2] == matriz[i][j + 3])) {
                        cont1++;
                    }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Datos encontrados: " + cont1);
    }
}
```

A la hora de correr el programa, me salta:

> " Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   6"

Yo quisiera que el contador muestre el valor de '1' ya que en la última fila se pueden apreciar 2 valores iguales, presiento que el error es en:

```
if ((matriz[i][j] == matriz[i][j + 1]) && (matriz[i][j + 1] == matriz[i][j + 2]) && (matriz[i][j + 2] == matriz[i][j + 3])) {
                    cont1++;
                }
```

Comment: Me olvidaba de comentar que lo que busco son elementos parecidos de forma HORIZONTAL

Comment: Te digo como encararlo: Depurando. Pon un punto de ruptura en tu programa y ejecútalo paso a paso, revisando cómo van cambiando los valores de los índices de los arrays, porque lo que te está pasando es que tu matriz es de 6x6 y estás intentando acceder a la posición 6 (no se si horizontal o verticalmente). Teniendo en cuenta que los índices de los arrays empiezan en 0, nunca deberías sobrepasar el índice 5 porque sino te dará esta excepción.

Comment: Lo que sucede es que pensaba que el programa frenaría si no encuentra valores siguientes, yo le coloco en las condiciones que sean menores a las dimensiones de la matriz, pero en el if donde comparo de manera HORIZONTAL los valores, me da errores por exceder el índice.

Comment: En un bucle para recorrer una matriz, si inicias el bucle en la posición 0, y terminas en el length, nunca puedes hacer referencia a j+1, ni a j + 2, ni a j más nada. Porque cuando j valga uno menos que la longitud, osea, el último ciclo del for, te estarías pasando fuera del límite. Si tu matriz que es de 6x6, cuando j sea 5, j < matriz[0].length se cumple, porque la length es 6, es la última vuelta, pero dentro del for haces cosas como matriz[i][ j+1], ahí ya te estás saliendo fuera. Ya no te digo nada de j + 2 o incluso j + 3 que estás haciendo. Dale otra pensada porque así no puede ser.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda SuperG280!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas generar un tercer bucle que te recorra la fila en la que te encuentras para comprar si son iguales y generar así una lógica que te permita identificar 4 letras iguales en la misma fila.

```
for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matriz[0].length; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < matriz[0].length; k++) {
            if (matriz[i][j] == matriz[i][k]) {
                cont1++;
            } // fin if
        }// fin for = k

        if(cont1 != 4) {
            cont1 = 0;
        } // fin if 
        else {
            System.out.println("Se ha encontrado en la linea: "+(i+1)+", 4 coincidencias de letras iguales");
        }
    } // fin for = j
} // fin for = i
```

Comment: Desde ya muchísimas gracias Ismael, cómo puedo colaborar para darte puntos o algo parecido?

Comment: El único problema que veo es que si tengo datos como PPPPQP (5 elementos P) no me los considera como que esa fila tenga al menos 4 elementos, trataré de modificar lo para que pueda funcionar un poco mejor, pero desde ya muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Solo tienes que cambiar la condición, yo la tengo que si es distinto a 4 reinicie el contador; en ese caso deberás cambiar el operador lógico para que cumpla con tus condiciones